# How to Change Titlebar Buttons WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, titlebar

I want to do a customization with the close, minimize and maximize buttons in a window titlebar. In some programs, the titlebar is different but I don't want to change the complete titlebar, only the buttons. Can anyone help me about that?

Comment: Change how it looks like, or what it does when pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customise the chrome of windows using windowchrome.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.windowchrome(v=vs.110).aspx

You can use that to entirely re-template your window.
Note that the class has moved since the following was written.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/

This can have odd side effects eg when you maximise a window in win10.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the title bar of a window belongs to the so-called **non-client area** of the window.
What that means is you **cannot** change the way the buttons look and you cannot add custom ones etc.

To do that, you need to roll your own window style or use a library that does that for you.

Some useful tutorials or starting points might be [this MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf/) or this tutorial on [how to create a custom window](https://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/custom_wpf_windows.htm).

To create your own window style, you can use this simple style as a base:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}"> 
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/> 
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/> 
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/> 
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>                        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!-- this displays the window title -->
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        <!-- the minimize button, using your own style -->
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyMinimizeButtonStyle}" 
                                Width="20" 
                                Height="20" />

                        <!-- the close button, using your own style -->
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyCloseButtonStyle}"
                                Width="20"
                                Height="20" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <!-- this displays the actual window content -->
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have a problem. I can't move the window :/

Comment: The MSDN link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WindowChrome to custom a window style:https://github.com/DinoChan/WindowDemo

This style does not use SystemParameters2 class because it is not exist in .net 4.5.